# Unable to send email using "sendmail"

Tags: php

I have installed sendmail on my Ubuntu Server 12.04.1. I am unable to send email from my domain (example: www.mydomain.com) and I don't see any error in the email log. I tried to update the path in php.ini as below

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Also:

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail

The PHP script I am using to send email (mydomain is just an example, I have a real domain). The result from the below code: "email not sent".

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8") ?>


<?php
    $subject = 'Test Mail Subject';
    $message = 'Test Mail Body';
    $to = 'anabash35@gmail.com';

    if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, "noreply@mydomain.org")){
        echo 'email sent';

    }
    else{
        echo 'email not sent';
    }
?>
```

In the email log (nano /var/log/mail.log), I get the below (I can't notice any error, my server name is server1):

> Oct  7 02:01:57 server1 sm-mta[4333]: r94L05At005852: to=, ctladdr= (33/33), delay=2+03:01:52, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp,$
>
> Oct  7 02:01:57 server1 sm-mta[4333]: r94MqOUW005456: to=, ctladdr= (33/33), delay=2+01:09:32, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp,$
>
> Oct  7 02:01:57 server1 sm-mta[4333]: r94MqNA8005453: to=, ctladdr= (33/33), delay=2+01:09:34, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp,$
>
> Oct  7 02:01:57 server1 sm-mta[4333]: r94M7xbi005307: to=, ctladdr= (33/33), delay=2+01:53:58, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp,$

I didn't touch any configuration file like sendmail.mc or sendmail.cf, etc.

I tried restarting the service: service sendmail restart. But with no luck :(

Would you please hint me what to do and how to debug the problem? Many thanks.

Cheers!

Comment: Try to remove @ and see what error php will rise

Comment: Is `sendmail_path` set to the correct value in php.ini?

Comment: You can't set a header after outputting to client. Move the `header` function to the top.

Comment: can you send mail from the command line?

Comment: Is this a test server on a local machine, or an actual server?

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate! I will try everything tomorrow, it is so late now and I am so tired! Will let you know the result ASAP.

Comment: @j08691: the test server is on actual server resides at my home, not the localhost.

Comment: Have a look at `nullmailer`. This little tool simulates a sendmail but instead of trying to deliver the mail by itself, it sends it to a configureable "real" smarthost. Trying to be a smarthost on a dialup connection normaly results in beeing detected as spam.

Comment: @bksi: I removed the @ and got no errors

Comment: The problem here is that you have this in your log: r94L05At005852: to=, Notice the empty "to"

Comment: @Dagon: I tried using this command: echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" anabash35@gmail.com, I didn't get any email and the result in the log file:

Oct  7 03:22:11 localhost sm-mta[2505]: r94M7xbi005307: to=<anabash35@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@server1> (33/33), delay=2+03:14:12, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=mailer=esmtp, pri=120359, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.79.26], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

Comment: @Anthony: It didn't change anything